# How to use ML for text classification in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification

I have two columns of data that is roughly 25k rows long. The first column contains a list of income statement line items and was created from OCR, so there are lots of errors in there. For example, There might be 20 line items for 'Income', but they might show as 'I ncome' or 'Imcome' or '...Incom', etc.

The second column contains a list of classifications that have been hand-coded so that line items can be categorized. For example, 'Miscellaneous Fees', 'Application Fees', 'Insurance Fees' would all be classified as 'Other Income'.

I'd like to train a model using my existing dataset to predict that 'I ncome' should be placed in the 'Income' category, 'Mscelaneous Fees' should be placed in the 'Other Income' category and so on.

My experience with ML is limited to the examples I've worked on in classes that all use continuous variables in the data sets, so I have practically zero experience working with text classification. I could convert the text categories to numerical values, but wouldn't be able to do so with the line items so I don't know that it would help me.

Can I accomplish this with sklearn? Pytorch? Tensorflow? Spark?

Really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

First you have to correct the words, because all Tensorflow and PyTorch pre trained models work in proper formatted words. For this you can use `pyspellchecker` or `autocorrect` in Python, for instance.

After that you will have to prepare data (try `nltk` or `spacy`), working on lower/upper case letters, removal of punctuation, special characters, maybe stemming and lemmatization. Then you will tokenize the phrases with `nltk.word_tokenize`.

Only after that you can map the first column to embeddings, vectors that represent that word/sentence.

For the embeddings, try this option, as is one of the fastest ones (choose the language in TF hub):

```
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text  # Imports TF ops for preprocessing.

BERT_MODEL = "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4"
PREPROCESS_MODEL = "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3"

sentences = [
  "Here We Go Then, You And I is a 1999 album by Norwegian pop artist Morten Abel. It was Abel's second CD as a solo artist.",
  "If it rains, it pours.", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."]

preprocess = hub.load(PREPROCESS_MODEL)
bert = hub.load(BERT_MODEL)

inputs = preprocess(sentences)
outputs = bert(inputs)
```

Then you will map X (first column, now lots of columns - embeddings) to Y (second column - classes). In this step you can use whatever classification algorithm you want: logistic regression, naive bayes, SVM, decision trees, random forests, gradient boosting or even a neural network.

Ah, remember also to turn your second column of classes in numeric classes with `dataframe['column_2'].cat.codes`